# jqplot legend event handler click

Tags: jqplot

hi i am trying to insert event handler to each line on the legend of jqplot
something like

$('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                alert(1);}););
but for the legend lines

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$('#chart-id tr.jqplot-table-legend').bind('click', function() {
    alert($(this).children().last().text());
});
```

So what this will do is `alert` the name of the series.